# HTTP Servlet Request processing Timeout

Tags: java, servlets

The requirement is to implement a timeout if HTTPServlet request cannot be processed in timed manner. e.g. if request processing takes more than 30 seconds then processing should timeout.

I've gone through servlet 3.1 specification but could not find any configuration that I can set to limit the request processing.

I've implemented the solution using Executor Service with fixed thread pool which is created in servlet context listener and in the servlet doGet method, I create a new Future by submitting a new Task with timeout. This works perfectly.

So just wanted to know if there is any other confiugration option available in application server or in web.xml?

I am using IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile Server and tried following timeouts but it is not working as I want to be:

1) tcpOptions - inactivityTimeout 
2) httpOptions - readTimeout and writeTimeout

Do you see any issues with this approach?

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    long responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis();     
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println("Service Request Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    ExecutorService threadPool = (ExecutorService) request
           .getServletContext().getAttribute("threadPool");     

    Future<String> future = threadPool.submit(new Task(request, response));

    try {

        pw.println("Started..");

        try {
            pw.println(future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pw.println("Finished!");

    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        pw.println("Terminated!");
        pw.println("Response time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - responseTime));
    }

}
```

Comment: HTTP Request Timeout is a property of the client, not the server.

Comment: There is no way in Liberty for having a timeout at the servlet level unless you are using asynchronous processing. Have you thought of using asynchronous processing?

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks. There is timeout on the client side as well. But lets say client-side timeout is 30 seconds.
Now client sends a request, server take 60 seconds to complete the response.
Client side timeout after 30 seconds but server thread that is doing the work still continues until it finishes the work.
Is that right? 

If yes, then I need to have timeout on the server side thread as well.

Comment: @mmulholl Thanks. I already looked Async Servlet and had prototype working on Tomcat but same code do not work on Liberty. Need to look further.  

As I said I got the server-side thread timeout working using Executor Service with fixed thread pool which is created in servlet context listener and in the servlet doGet method, I create a new Future by submitting a new Task with timeout.

Do you see any issues with this approch?

Comment: @mmulholl I added the code to message. Please take a look and let me know if this approach is good or not.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the actual functionality, no it's not a good approach. You're basically saying "I hope this won't take more than 60 seconds, because even the client gave up at 30 seconds". That's not the kind of uncertainty you want to have in a production system. Instead you should make sure that the individual actions (database, webservice etc. calls) performed by the request don't take more time than you think. If your clients are timing out, your application is broken. Fix your code, get a larger server if necessary, don't try to work around it like this.

Comment: I do not like your approach because you are processing the inbound request on a new thread and servlets are expected to either run on the thread on which they are invoked, or to use asynchronous processing. For the thread which you create to execute the task the thread context is not moved so depending on what the task does it may not work. If you are having problems getting an asynchronous servlet working on Liberty I would be very happy to help.